# legends with text to the right of line styles

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way in matplotlib to position the text in legend to the right of the line styles?

That is, I want a legend that looks like this

[image: Legend with text]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen from the [`legend` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend), there is a `markerfirst` argument which can be set to False to make the markers appear last.

```
plt.legend(markerfirst=False)
```

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot([1,2,3],[3-i, i/3., i], marker="o",label="label {}".format(i))

plt.legend(markerfirst=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]